# How can I prevent warping while hardwood floor is stored for reuse?

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I'm pulling up 1000 sq ft of hardwood floors to reuse in a couple months. They'll be stored in the same room they're pulled up from so the humidity levels will remain the same, minus seasonal change (which is pretty drastic in Chicago). The longer boards pulled a few months ago have warped pretty badly.

Any advice on how to prevent warping?

Comment: So between where they were laid and where they are stored is there a change of humidity? Temperature? How are the boards supported? Once every 3 feet or every 10 inches?

Comment: Once re-laid they should re-flatten out, just as they did before removing.

Comment: Honestly, this is really 2 questions in 1 and will be difficult to accept a "correct" answer. (Take the [tour] to see how we do things differently here.) Edit to remove your last sentence and ask it as a whole new question.

Answer (score 3):

At the time the flooring is pulled, it should be de-nailed and carefully stacked so it lays flat. You could leave the nails in, but it will take a lot more room to store the same material. To get past the issue of the nails not allowing the material to stack neatly, each layer needs "sticking" or "driers" to give rom for the nails to lay without making the flooring rest at angles or digging into other flooring that will require more sanding to clean up the potentially deep scratches. If the flooring is going to be stored elsewhere, as in not in the same building that it is to go back down in the humidity will adversely affect the flooring, making driers necessary. The weight of the flooring upon itself will aid in keeping the material flat.

My suggestion to you is to stack the flooring with driers about every 2' apart. You will need driers every layer so the accumulated weight of the material will help press the flooring flat as the humidity of the flooring reacclimates to the house. This does mean it needs to be in the house it is to go in.

If there is a twist left in the material, depending how wide it is, or how bad the twist is, since it was not mentioned, some can be flattened as it is nailed down. It will not make the floor easy to put down, but it could work if it is not twisted too badly.

It may not flatten out, it may. If the flooring has the chance to return to the original moisture content at the time it was taken up, my belief is that it will go back to flat if you give it the conditions to.

Comment: Just to be clear, the stickers (as they're called) need to be between _every_ layer of the flooring to allow even air movement around _all_ the flooring.

Comment: And so long as the boards are fastened without room to move and the warped boards are flattened like the non warped boards, there won't be creaking? Before pulling up the floors my hardwood floors had no creaking so I'm nervous I'm going to mess it up. I also updated the question to state that I'm storing them in the same place so same humidity.

Comment: Yes that will be the case. You will need to spend time cleaning the crud that is on the edges of the flooring where there were gaps in the flooring at one time and dirt, floor finish etc. fell in and got stuck real good to the edges. This will keep the flooring from drawing up tight if it stays. It should take no more than a piece of hardwood with square edges to clean off while you are inspecting each piece for reuse. If all has been in the same building, after all the nails are pulled, broken tongues and grooves cut off or set aside, you can bundle them up with plastic for easy handling.

Comment: That is as long as they have not been elsewhere to gain moisture so that is has to be lost again where it sets now. The plastic wrap only needs to be on the ends, in the middle too if the pieces are really long.